# Cancelled order showing under My Account - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm running a woocommerce website.

whenever a customer cancels an order, it shows up under the customers account information page. to the point it "drowns out" the completed orders the customer has made, without a "page 2, page 3" reference.

in other words, after so many canceled orders, the customer won't be able to see what the hokey he's ordered and completed as ordered in the first place.

So my question is,

IS there a way to remove "canceled" orders from showing under "my account" for my customer? and only show completed orders?

or add a page 2, page 3, (increasing the maximum number of orders shown per page?)

This is a woocommerce Question.....

ps. i've been looking at 
my-account.php
my-orders.php

the answer is definitely in editing my-orders.php....

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in my-orders.php. You need to use `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query` filter

Add the following code to your theme's functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_orders' );
function custom_my_orders( $args ) {

    if (($key = array_search('wc-cancelled', $args['post_status'])) !== false) {
        unset($args['post_status'][$key]);
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Here's the list of order types:

```
Array ( [0] => wc-pending [1] => wc-processing [2] => wc-on-hold [3] => wc-completed [4] => wc-cancelled [5] => wc-refunded [6] => wc-failed [7] => wc-shipped )
```