# Remove cancelled WooCommerce orders from customers my account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, orders

I had been using [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332131/cancelled-order-showing-under-my-account-woocommerce/35345296#35345296) and since WooCommerce version 2.6+, this code **is not working anymore**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_orders' );
function custom_my_orders( $args ) {
    if (($key = array_search('wc-cancelled', $args['post_status'])) !== false) {
        unset($args['post_status'][$key]);
    }
    return $args;
}
```

As the old template **`my-orders.php`** is no longer used.

How can I do this using the latest version of Woocommerce?

Thanks.

Reference: [Cancelled order showing under My Account - Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332131/cancelled-order-showing-under-my-account-woocommerce/35345296#35345296)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all **`my account`** templates have drastically changed with woocommerce version 2.6+. In the new template **`orders.php`**, **`woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query`** hook is not used anymore.

There is no similar hooks in the new **`orders.php`** template.

But there is a simple alternative [customizing](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) **`orders.php`** template with a condition:

```
<?php
/**
 * Orders
 *
 * Shows orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.6.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>

<?php if ( $has_orders ) : ?>

    <table class="woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) :
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order );

// ==>          Displays all customer orders except 'cancelled' ones
                if ( $order->get_status() != 'cancelled' ) : 

                    $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                    ?>
                    <tr class="order">
                        <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                            <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                                <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                        <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                                    </a>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <?php
                                        $actions = array(
                                            'pay'    => array(
                                                'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                                'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                            ),
                                            'view'   => array(
                                                'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                                'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                                            ),
                                            'cancel' => array(
                                                'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                                'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                            )
                                        );
                                        if ( ! $order->needs_payment() ) {
                                            unset( $actions['pay'] );
                                        }
                                        if ( ! in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                            unset( $actions['cancel'] );
                                        }
                                        if ( $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order ) ) {
                                            foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </td>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>

                <?php endif; // and here ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders_pagination' ); ?>

    <?php if ( 1 < $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-Pagination">
            <?php if ( 1 !== $current_page ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--previous button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $current_page - 1 ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Previous', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $current_page !== intval( $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--next button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $current_page + 1 ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
        <a class="woocommerce-Button button" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Go Shop', 'woocommerce' ) ?>
        </a>
        <?php _e( 'No order has been made yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>
```

I just use **`if ( $order->get_status() != 'cancelled' )`** to filter orders and avoid displaying orders with **`'cancelled'`** status.

Reference: [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the statuses explicitly in the `$args['status']`. 
The latest version of WooCommerce replaces `$args['post_status']` with `$args['status']` and has no values set for `$args['status']` by default. So you can't unset any values!

Copy it in the `functions.php` file or just replace your code with the following:

```
/**
 * Exclude orders by status in My Account
 * 
 * @param $args
 * @return mixed
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_orders' );
function custom_my_orders($args ) {
    $args['status'] = array(
        'wc-pending',
        'wc-processing',
        'wc-on-hold',
        'wc-completed',
//      'wc-cancelled',
        'wc-refunded',
        'wc-failed',
    );

    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code and works easy and perfect: [Hide orders with status (Pending Payment) on WooCommerce My Account page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155814/hide-orders-with-status-pending-payment-on-woocommerce-my-account-page)

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'unset_pending_payment_orders_from_my_account', 10, 1 );
    
    
    function unset_pending_payment_orders_from_my_account( $args ) {
        $statuses = wc_get_order_statuses();    
        unset( $statuses['wc-pending'] );
        $args['status'] = array_keys( $statuses );
        return $args;
    }
```